# What is the meaning of this Arabic tawiz?

Tags: arabic-translation, tawiz

My sister in law (husband's sister) gave me a piece of paper for keeping that in my room for the betterment of my husband on which something is written in Arabic. I can read but can't know the meaning.  What does it mean?

[image: Arabic tawiz]

Answer (score 2):

Initially in regard to the Taweez I should declare that it is an acceptable practice between Muslims (Sunni, Shia..). Hence we cannot deny it. I likewise ought to mention that as far as I know, whatever human does not believe in, then probably it won’t be effective for him/her. As a result I suggest you to change your belief regarding Taweez and be sure about it to obtain a nicer consequence.

In regard to the meaning of the mentioned Taweez (which you showed the pic of it), seemingly this consists of two parts. The initial part is related to the Sural Al-i-Imran:134 which is shown as below (by its meaning):

> الَّذِينَ يُنفِقُونَ فِي السَّرَّاءِ وَالضَّرَّاءِ وَالْكَاظِمِينَ
>   الْغَيْظَ وَالْعَافِينَ عَنِ النَّاسِ ۗ وَاللَّـهُ يُحِبُّ
>   الْمُحْسِنِينَ ﴿١٣٤
>
> Who spend [in the cause of Allah] during ease and hardship and who
>   restrain anger and who pardon the people - and Allah loves the doers
>   of good; (134)

But in regard to the second part of it, to be honest, it doesn’t seem so clear, but on the whole is looks as a dua or a verse which is related to the friendship or kindness (between people) which perhaps be able to increase the kindness between you and your husband. Trust Allah mate.

---

**Reference(s):**

- [wikifeqh.ir](http://wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AA%D8%B9%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B0)
- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/3:134)

Comment: The last words or line of the second part are readable and mean وَأَلِّفْ بَيْنَ قُلُوبِهِمْ (And brought together their hearts.) see for example the beginning of :http://legacy.quran.com/8/63